# NextAuth: JWT callback returning object

Tags: javascript, jwt, next.js, strapi, next-auth

I've working in a project with **Next.js (11.1.2) + NextAuth (^4.0.5) + Strapi(3.6.8)**.

I'm using Next Auth credentials provider and it's working fine. But I need to access a few user information using `session`, so I tried to do this using `jwt` and `session` callbacks.

When I log response from strapi inside `authorize()`, I receive `{ jwt:{}, user:{} }`, so it's ok.

```
//[...nextauth.js]

async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(process.env.CREDENTIALS_AUTH_URL, credentials)
          if (data) {
            //console.log('data: ', data) //this is ok
            return data;
          }
          else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
},
```

But, in `jwt` callback, when I log `token`, i'm getting a bizarre obj with `{token:{token:{token:{...}}}`:

```
// [...nextauth.js] callback:{ jwt: async (token) => { console.log(token) }}

token: {
  token: {
    token: {},
    user: {
      jwt: ...,
      user: [Object]
    },
    account: { type: 'credentials', provider: 'credentials' },
    isNewUser: false,
    iat: ...,
    exp: ...,
    jti: ...
  }
}
```

And `account` and `user` is always undefined inside that callbacks.

Finally, when I get `session` from `useSession` in a page, I get this:

```
// console.log(session) in any page

{ 
  session: {
    expires: "2022-01-12T19:27:53.429Z"
    user: {} // empty
  },
  token:{
    token:{
      account: {type: 'credentials', provider: 'credentials'}
      exp: ...
      iat: ...
      isNewUser: false
      jti: "..."
      token: {} // empty
      user: { //exactly strapi response
         jwt:{...}
         user:{...}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All examples I've found aren't handling this objects with this confuse structure and I don't know if I missing something out. Can you help me?

This is my `[...nextauth].js`:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import axios from 'axios';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: '...',
      credentials: {
        email: {label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "email@provider.com"},
        password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {

        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(process.env.CREDENTIALS_AUTH_URL, credentials)
          if (data) {
            //console.log('data: ', data)
            return data;
          }
          else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    })
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // 30 days
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    encryption: true,
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async (token, account) => {

      console.log('### JWT CALLBACK ###')
      console.log('token: ', token)
      console.log('account: ', account)

      return token;
    },
  
    session: async (session, token, user) => {
      console.log('### SESSION CALLBACK ###')
      console.log('session: ', session)
      console.log('user: ', token)
      console.log('user: ', user)

      return session;
    }
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/signin',
    signOut: '/signin',
    error: '/signin'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5):

try pls:

```
- session(session, tokenOrUser)
+ session({ session, token, user })
```

```
- jwt(token, user, account, OAuthProfile, isNewUser)
+ jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser })
```

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/upgrade-v4#callbacks